# working with upsource 3.5 on ubuntu server

Tags: software-installation

I'm having trouble with websocket :

```
WebSocket transport is not available.
```

the full warning :

```
Warning: WebSocket transport is not available, using polling (if this message appears repeatedly, 
    please refer to our documentation for troubleshooting: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/3.5/proxy-configuration.html)
```

I follow the tutorial exactly but I got the same error and I use nginx configuration without ssl

What is going wrong ?

result of :  `nginx -v`

```
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
```

Comment: Which tutorial are you following exactly?

Comment: the upsource documentation : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/3.5/proxy-configuration.html)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `nginx -v`

Comment: Related: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: @ElderGeek i edit the post :)

Comment: Is Upsource hosted under yke root URL (/) on your virtual host?

Comment: @ElderGeek yes i can edit the post to show you my nginx conf